# Apache Wicket bookmarkable url added one additional parameter to the link, why?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicked-pdf, wicket-1.6

my map is

mountPage("/page/#{code}/#{name}", Page.class);

but when I click on the link

`localhost/page/10/toy?2`

wicket add also one parameter like a counter, when I refresh the page I have

`localhost/page/10/toy?3`

why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because your page are stateful, Wicket manages its own states to your page by appending this "counter". This way, when your user navigate backward using its browser built-in functionnality, the page is displayed has it has been previously.

If you don't want such a parameter in your URL, you'll need to dig out and eradicate every stateful component in your pages.

Comment: Thank you, how can I sole this?
 params.add("link", components.getModelObject().getPermalink());
                        params.add("code", code);
                        
                        Link link = new BookmarkablePageLink("link",
                                OrderPage.class, params);   
                        
                        link.add(new Label("linksel", "Select"));
                        components.add(link);                
I am just click on url and second page extended BasePage

Comment: You can help Wicket by defining `getStatelessHint()` returning true in your base page. I'm afraid you'll need to fire the debugger in order to find which component is stateful in order to suppress this in your url.

Comment: How we can remove that counter from url?

Answer (score 1):

You can create

```
public class MountedMapperWithoutPageComponentInfo extends MountedMapper {

public MountedMapperWithoutPageComponentInfo(String mountPath, Class<? extends IRequestablePage> pageClass) {
    super(mountPath, pageClass, new PageParametersEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void encodePageComponentInfo(Url url, PageComponentInfo info) {

}

@Override
public Url mapHandler(IRequestHandler requestHandler) {
    if (requestHandler instanceof ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return super.mapHandler(requestHandler);
    }
}
```

}

and map page on Application class like this

```
mount(new MountedMapperWithoutPageComponentInfo("/page/#{code}/#{name}", Page.class));
```